# java.net.UnknownHostException - Zuul and Eureka not working inside Docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I´ve been trying to validade my microservices on a Docker structure, where i connect everything through linking containers but i´m not having success when trying to pass through an API Gateway with Zuul.

Basically i have theses microservices:

- config-server
- boutique-eureka-server
- api-gateway
- product-service

All of these start with success but i can´t acess the product-service behing the api-gateway.

My code is all at:

https://github.com/kalilmvp/myboutique/

along with the docker commands that i´ve used.

The error usually is:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
```

In my later tests i´ve been also having this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: product-service
```

You can check it on the branch **docker**

Comment: But micro services without docker are well registered on the eureka server? Because by checking your client configuration I don't see you giving them the address of the eureka server.

Comment: Hi @FrancescRecio, yes they are. This problem is only happening when using Docker. Where would i put the address? Because i did configure like this on application.yml, which is inherited by all the other configurations:

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${SERVICE_URL_DEFAULT_ZONE}

Answer (score 0):

Docker advises not to use `--link` option to link the containers and therefore this switch of `docker run` is deprecated.

There are many problems creating end-to-end links, like for example environment variables are being shared between 2 linked containers (imagine different values of **JAVA_HOME** for example).

Instead try coordinating your services using `docker compose` or define network using docker:

```
$ docker network create my-net
$ docker create --name my-eureka --network my-net --publish 8888:80 eureka:latest
...
$ docker network disconnect my-net my-eureka
```

Find more info [in the docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/##differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Comment: HI @diginoise, thanks for the answer. Yeah i´ve thought about using docker-compose but first was trying to figure this out. Thinking that the use of **--link--** not being advised anymore, it´s better that i try a different approach. I´ll try that and will come back with updates.

Thanks again!

Comment: @KalilPeixoto no problem and good luck! Oh, and also feel free to upvote the answer whenever you fill like it ;)

Comment: i´ve tried the docker compose solution but i ended up a problem. I configured just 3 services and even though on the last 2 i put the dependency to the first one, they all start simultaneously. That created a error of Connection, cause the configuration server haven´t started yet.

I found a "solution" using a waiting script, but i just didn´t like it. I just didn´t get it, if you define that your service depends on the first one, it should wait for it, no ?